# Itext having issues while rendering the fonts

Tags: itext

I am trying to render a pdf using url but i am getting the below exception

*Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.lowagie.text.pdf.BaseFont.getCharBBox(C)[I
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextFontResolver$FontDescription.setMetricDefaults(ITextFontResolver.java:679)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextFontResolver$FontDescription.(ITextFontResolver.java:610)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextFontResolver.addCourier(ITextFontResolver.java:410)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextFontResolver.createInitialFontMap(ITextFontResolver.java:390)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextFontResolver.(ITextFontResolver.java:52)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer.(ITextRenderer.java:115)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer.(ITextRenderer.java:102)
    at com.converter.pdf.MapInPDF.convertItextUrl(MapInPDF.java:132)
    at com.converter.pdf.MapInPDF.main(MapInPDF.java:148)*

Below is my code

```
    try {
        System.out.println("start");
        String url = "http://122.181.151.113:8080/Airometric/Pages/exportPdf.jsf?loggedInUserName=admin&testCaseName=Nexus520";

        String outputFile = "D://firstdoc.pdf";
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

        ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
        renderer.setDocument(url);
        renderer.layout();
        renderer.createPDF(os);

        os.close();
        System.out.println("end");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Any suggestion would be really helpful.

Comment: Incompatible versions of xhtmlrenderer and iText on you classpath, I assume.

Comment: Is this fixed now? Which combination of latest maven versions for xhtmlrenderer and iText should I use now to not face this issue anymore?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it works with iText 2.0.8 only. *sad*